# how to change the localhost to ip address

Tags: .net

I am working on asp.net application 
when i run using http:\\localhost:1322 i can see the site.

but if i give my ip address http:\\111.111.11.11:1322 , i get page not found. even in my desktop

Is there any change in setting to be done. because of this i cant send the url to other people in the team.

the ip address i am typing is correct :)

any guidancewil be of gr8 help

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Answer (score 4):

The development server in Visual Studio is local-only.  You'd have to use IIS to serve it to other members of your team.  I'm assuming you're using the visual studio dev server based on the problem.  It's called Cassini, FYI.

You can change this setting in the Project Property pages, if you have IIS installed, that is.

Comment: Take a look at UltraDev's Cassini 2.0: http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ as an alternative to full IIS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is for stack overflow.
Your problem is more likely with firewall.